# Ubuntu 22.04 boot issues

Tags: boot, grub2

I have run an update and upgrade from the command line and now have a boot issue:

First boot (*) > nothing happens. Blank screen, no splash, nothing.

(*) reboot from the running system is the same.

I then shutdown the machine using a ten seconds hold on the power button.

Second boot > I get the grub menu, and subsequent boot works fine. Both the old and the new version boot.

What could be changing between a normal boot, and a boot following a power down of the system?

*** Possible red herring alert***

I wonder if it's something to do with an ongoing frustration that I have an SD card and the boots seem to swap the disk identifiers indiscriminately

Sometimes I have the SD card as `/dev/mmcblk0` and the boot disk as `/dev/mmcblk1`, and sometimes the other way around.

Is it possible that the update has got the bootloader confused?

I have tried `sudo grub-install /dev/mmcblkX` (where X is the correct disk for the O/S) from the running system, followed by `sudo grub-update`, but it's no better.